# It doesn't send the data from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have lots of layouts and activites and fragments. There are tabs in one activity called `Hastane1` and it has four tabs in it. They don't have any problem but one of them has. I wanted to send a data from one Activity to a Fragment. They are seperate. Fragment is in `Hastane1` activity but `Haberlesme1` activity is in another place. It supposed to send the numbers which i entered in the activity called `Haberlesme1` to the textView in the fragment called `Hastane1Tab3Frag` which is a tab of `Hastane1`.
The Android Studio itself doesn't have any errors but when i run the app on my phone, it stops when i pressed the button called "Gönder" (`@id/button8`).
Haberlesme1 (Activity):

```
package com.example.projev021.İllerPackage.KocaeliPackage.GebzePackage.GebzeFragments.Hastane1Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.projev021.HaberlesmePackage.Haberlesme1;
import com.example.projev021.R;

public class Hastane1Tab3Frag extends Fragment {

    Button goster;
    TextView sonucText;
    int sayi=0;
    Haberlesme1.Ogrenci ogr;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.hastane1_tab3,container,false);

        goster=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button13);
        sonucText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        goster.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sonucText.setText(sayi);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public void sendData(int birinciSayi) {
        this.sayi=birinciSayi;

    }

    public void sendOgrenci(Haberlesme1.Ogrenci ogrenci) {
        this.ogr=ogrenci;
    }
}
```

haberlesme1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"

        android:fontFamily="@font/lineto_circular_black"

        android:text="@string/kackisivar"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"

        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lineto_circular_black"

        android:text="@string/gonder"
        android:textColor="#FFC107"
        android:textSize="30sp"

        android:onClick="calistir"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hastane1Tab3Frag (Fragment):

```
package com.example.projev021.İllerPackage.KocaeliPackage.GebzePackage.GebzeFragments.Hastane1Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.projev021.HaberlesmePackage.Haberlesme1;
import com.example.projev021.R;

public class Hastane1Tab3Frag extends Fragment {

    Button goster;
    TextView sonucText;
    int sayi=0;
    Haberlesme1.Ogrenci ogr;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.hastane1_tab3,container,false);

        goster=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button13);
        sonucText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        goster.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sonucText.setText(sayi);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public void sendData(int birinciSayi) {
        this.sayi=birinciSayi;

    }

    public void sendOgrenci(Haberlesme1.Ogrenci ogrenci) {
        this.ogr=ogrenci;
    }
}
```

hastane1tab3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"

        android:fontFamily="@font/lineto_circular_black"

        android:text="@string/kisisayisi_"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:fontFamily="@font/lineto_circular_black"

        android:text=""
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lineto_circular_black"

        android:text="@string/goster"
        android:textColor="#FFC107"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And the screenshots:
[image: Activity]
[image: Fragment]

Comment: do you have crash log ?

Comment: @LenaBru unfortunately it only crashes when i use the app, it doesn't show any crash log from the IDE. i guess...

Comment: change your app from what it says, to the dead app and look in the error console
There are two dropdowns at the top of the logcat, one is your device, the 2nd next to it is your running app, if you click that, it will have one that says [Dead] - switch to that one
Then select the 3rd drop down - to the right of the 2nd one, and choose error there, and copy paste that here please

Comment: May be sending the data to the second activity and sending the data from the second activity to desired fragment when creating or updating(from the second activity) of the fragment help you.Also it is possible to execute a method of second activity in a fragment of the second activity when changing tab or by notifydatasetchanged